# Magic the gathering question

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Sarkhan the masterless +1 ability. It becomes a 4/4 dragon with flying. Can it attack that turn? Does it depend if the planeswalker was on the field already or just played?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately I had to close your question because it has already been answered elsewhere, this is how the site works. Please refer to the [Help center](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help) on how to ask questions and which. We will gladly answer any other question you might have.

Comment: Re "*Does it depend if the planeswalker was on the field already or just played?*", Yes.

Answer (score 0):

From the rulings in Gatherer:

> A planeswalker that becomes a creature due to Sarkhan’s first loyalty ability can’t attack unless you’ve controlled it continuously since your turn began.

Once it is a creature; it follows the summoning sickness rules just like any other creature.

Comment: Fun thing to keep in mind and what won me the pre-release at the time. You can give the creature haste with a spell, as you can with any other creature so it can attack right away. The thing what did it for me was the static ability of Samut, Tyrant Smasher. Which gives haste to creatures you control. Together with Menace from Angrath, Captain of Chaos.